# Flutter : How change modify unmodifiable map

Tags: flutter, maps, unmodifiable

I have list like this in provider:

```
List orders=[]:
void getOrders(){
  orders = [
        {"id":1,
        "order":[
                {"id":1,"name":"mike"},
                {"id":2,"name":"john"},
                {"id":3,"name":"smith"}
                ]
       },
        {"id":1,
        "order":[
                {"id":1,"name":"roz"},
                {"id":2,"name":"sam"},
                {"id":3,"name":"ruby"}
                ]
       },
 ];
  notifyListeners();
}
```

in provider when I use this methos to chane indexed order with another:

```
void changeOrder(orderIndex,item){
   orders[orderIndex].update("order",(val)=>item);
   notifyListeners();
}
```

I get this error `type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => Object' of 'update'`

and when I use this :

```
void changeOrder(orderIndex,item){
   orders[orderIndex]["order"]=item;
   notifyListeners();
}
```

I get this error `Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map`

**Add More Details**

the item in changeOrder method comes from screen contain orders :

```
var item = List.from(orders[index]);
```

Comment: void changeOrder(orderIndex,item){ what's the item you are passing here?

Comment: @KaushikChandru somrthing like this [{"id":1,"name":"mike"},{"id":2,"name":"john"},{"id":3,"name":"smith"}]

Comment: Both cases working for me

Comment: Include how you are creating the item

Comment: @KaushikChandru when I print type of item gave me : List<dynamic>

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I will add more details

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have add some details

Comment: @KaushikChandru  I have add some details

Answer (score 0):

`orders` type  is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. While reading the `item`, it will be a map instead of list.

```dart
Map item = Map.from(orders[index]);
```

And you can use both way you;ve tried.

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> orders = [];
void getOrders() {
  orders = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "order": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "mike"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "john"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "smith"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "order": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "roz"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "sam"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "ruby"}
      ]
    },
  ];
}

void changeOrder(orderIndex, item) {
  orders[orderIndex]["order"] = item;
  // orders[orderIndex].update("order", (val) => item);
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  getOrders();
  print(orders);
  Map item = Map.from(orders[1]);
  changeOrder(1, item);

  print(orders);
}
```